# Send a string from a viewController to another one

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

Please, before you mark this question as duplicate, I want to know why my code is failing, not to be send to another one that is working.

I am a newbie in swift and I would like to send a variable "um_words" (which is calculated when a button is clicked) from a viewController when the same button is clicked, save that variable in the secondViewController and show it in a textView. To do so I have tried with many modifications of this code, which is giving no errors in the console but not showing the value of the variable on the textView:

**1st VC**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TransViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var trad_text: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var buttonTrad: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var labelsitoh: UILabel!

var num_words = 0

@IBAction func butCalc(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let text = trad_text.text

    num_words =  (text?.components(separatedBy: " ").count)!-1

     func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        var DestViewController : PaymentViewController = segue.destination as! PaymentViewController

        DestViewController.num_words =  String(num_words)
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    trad_text!.layer.borderWidth = 1
    trad_text!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    trad_text!.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.26, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0).cgColor
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

**2nd VC**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class PaymentViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var labelImport: UITextView!

var num_words = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    labelImport.text = num_words

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

I have ab hypothesis of why it is not working: the function "prepare" is not being called; it only goes to next VC when the button is clicked...

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not seeing anything in prepareForSegue. Read up (here and everywhere) on how this is done. Please, do your own homework.

Comment: Your prepare function is inside of another function which is why it isn't being called.

Comment: My function is inside a function that should be called when a button is clicked. It does not work if I do it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The func prepare should be outside of the button action, it will be called when segue is triggered.

```
@IBAction func butCalc(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let text = trad_text.text

    num_words =  (text?.components(separatedBy: " ").count)!-1

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    var DestViewController : PaymentViewController = segue.destination as! PaymentViewController

    DestViewController.num_words =  String(num_words)

}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to use the same button to do the two functions. I need to do first the fund butCalc and then the prepare, and the way you coded, it will do only prepare, won't it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer shows a value of the variable of "0". It must be for the global variable I created, but if I delete it, then an error "use of unresolved identifier "num_words" " appears

Comment: Did you add segue from the button to the second VC in the storyboard ?

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem is that believe the global var num_words is not being modified

Comment: Did you check your var before launch your segue ?

Comment: What do you mean by check my var?

Comment: print `num_words` in `prepareForSegue `

Comment: Did you set the class of the secondVC in the storyboard ? Please check this example project i uploaded. Its working like u want. [link]https://github.com/StefanNestorov/AnswerToSegueQuestion

Comment: Thank you so much for your implication @StefanNestorov it worked! The problem was that i was not giving an identifier to the segue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

See:

```
IBAction func butCalc(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let text = trad_text.text
    num_words =  (text?.components(separatedBy: " ").count)!-1
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier") {
        var destViewController : PaymentViewController = segue.destination as! PaymentViewController
        destViewController.num_words =  String(num_words)
    }
}
```

You have create a function in another function...
Please try this.

PS: I did not test this code

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried your code and for me it seems correct but the second viewController is showing nothing on the screen

Comment: This is another problem that you didn't mentioned! If it solve your problem marks thus answer as solution! Glad to help you

Comment: Well, I wanted to mean that the textView is not showing the value of the variable

Comment: Can you add a `print(num_words)` in your `viewDidLoad` method, to be sure you passed your var

Comment: I did it and it is printing nothing in the console

Comment: Try to replace `var num_words = String()` by `var num_words: String`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still printing nothing in the console